# Getting data from the Dota 2 client (Source 2 engine)

Tags: parsing, client-server, game-development

I realize that my question might be a bit too specific. Nevertheless, let me quickly give an intro to the problem.

**Some background info:**
Dota 2 is a Multiplayer Online Battle Arena (MOBA) game developed by Valve. The game runs on the Source 2 engine. As far as I understand, there are two components to the game: the client and Valve's server.

Dota 2 has guilds which can include up to 50 members. The guild could be thought of as a Discord channel. Guild members can chat and queue (arrange a guild party of 5) to play the game.

Each guild member is expected to earn game points by just playing with other guild members.

**The problem:**
The game itself has a very rudimentary guild management and statistics system. I'm interested in a way to pull guild-wide accessible data from the Dota 2 client. The data points I'm interested in are "player name" and "player's points".

**Possible workarounds:**
I could collect this data by hand for all 50 members, but this is very tedious, especially if I want to do that on a weekly basis.

I know that Dota 2 has a console (similar to a console in CS:GO, Team Fortress, Left 4 Dead and Half-Life). I've scanned through console commands but couldn't find anything relevant.

I'm also aware of the [OpenDota API](https://docs.opendota.com/). However, it seems it is for gathering match statistics rather than guild data.

**My question is:**
Is it somehow possible to dump data from the Dota 2 client and then parse it using Python? Perhaps, more generally, how would I find out potential ways of getting the guild data?

Here is the guild table in Dota that I would like to pull:
[image]